# Which output formats support action="passthrough"? (XHTML doesn't - frowny)

Tags: xhtml, dita

We have source documentation in DITA that targets multiple products using the "product" attribute. Our publishing tool supports XHTML input and supports conditionalized output, but 'dita' seems to ignore action="passthrough" for the xhtml target.

What other output formats support action="passthrough"? Maybe I can hack up a temporary workaround. Thanks!

Comment: What is your "publishing tool"?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, it was considered that in XHTML-based outputs you cannot have "data-" attributes because they are not part of the XHTML transitional specification. So the passthrough works only for HTML 5.
So this XSLT stylesheet:

```
     dita-ot\plugins\org.dita.xhtml\xsl\dita2xhtml-util.xsl
```

matches all such data- attributes and eliminates them:

```
 <xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-')]" mode="add-xhtml-ns" priority="10"/>
```

I see you opened an issue on the DITA OT issues list:

https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/2955

I added the same comment on the issue and maybe we'll discuss there more with the DITA OT devs.